# How can I set a click listener only for Button in angular application

Tags: angular, onclicklistener

I just want to implement a event (click) listner into my angular application, which is only for button. buttons will be created dynamically.

the code looks like this:

```
  constructor(
    private companyService: CompanyService,
    elementRef: ElementRef,
    renderer: Renderer,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, "onclick", event => {
      // if (event.target.innerHTML) {
      //   this.searchByVin(event.target.innerHTML);
      // }
    });
  }


private setCustomValueFunction() {
    this.customValueFunction = (
      elemValue: string,
      elemKey: string,
      elem: {}
    ) => {
      if (elemKey === "vin") {
        elemValue = `<div class="gridster-item-content"><button (click)="searchByVin(${elemValue})">${elemValue}</button></div>`;
      }
      if (elemKey === "status") {
        elemValue = `
        <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>`;
      }
      return elemValue;
    };
  }
```

this 2 functions, which can create a button dynamically and in constructor will set a click event listner, but this listner is for all click event, the question is, how can I set this listner only for buttons.

Best Regards,

Leo

Comment: Is there any reason you can't create the buttons in the template with a mix of `*ngFor` and `*ngIf`? Wherever possible, you want to avoid directly editing the DOM in Angular apps.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward method is to do it via `html` like so:

```
<button id="button1" (click)="myFunction()"> Button text </button>
```

You have to implement the `myFunction()` in your javascript file.

Another way is to find that button on your javascript file like this:

```
document.getElementById('button1')
```

and add an event listener.

Comment: Hi, the button is created dynamically, and I implement with typscript, How can i get button id?

Comment: You can set it the same way you create the `click()` attribute

Comment: can u give me more inforamtion?

Comment: `<button **id=${elemValue}** (click)="searchByVin(${elemValue})">${elemValue}</button>`

Comment: where should I add the code document.getElementById('button1') in my typscript code?

Comment: It should be added after creating dynamically each button, so you can tell assign each but its callback

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requiremrnt and I used Componetn to achive this. 
Try Following this.
1. Create Component with your button

```
<div nxRow *ngIf="editMode">
<div nxCol="12,12,6">
  <button nxButton='secondary' (click)='save()'>save</button>
</div>
<div nxCol="12,12,6">
  <button nxButton='secondary' (click)='cancel()'>cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
<div nxRow *ngIf="!editMode">
<div nxCol="12,12,12">
<button nxButton='secondary' (click)='edit()'>edit</button>
</div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
// tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
selector: 'az-save-edit-button',
templateUrl: './save-edit-button.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./save-edit-button.component.css']
})
export class SaveEditButtonComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() divId = null;
@Output() btnClick = new EventEmitter();
editMode = false;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

save() {
this.editMode = false;
this.btnClick.emit({divId: this.divId, action: 'save'});
}

edit() {
this.editMode = true;
this.btnClick.emit({divId: this.divId, action: 'edit'});
}

cancel() {
this.editMode = false;
this.btnClick.emit({divId: this.divId, action: 'cancel'});
}

}
```

2. create dynamically from parent component(pass your id)

```
<az-save-edit-button [divId]="3" (btnClick)="functionCall($event)"></az-save-edit-button>
```

on clik you will get the button id. Modify this to suit your requirement

Comment: that is not what I mean, because the buttons will be also created dynamically, you can not know which id you click

Comment: Hope this helps, Try passing an id to the component--> [divId]="3" and then emit it on click from component  --> .emit({divId: this.divId, action: 'cancel'});